# Reduce multidimensional with string and numbers array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, reduce

I have some idea of how reduce works, but I'm having problem with a multidimensional array. How can I reduce this:

```
y = [['x', 0.5], ['x', 0.5], ['z', 2], ['z', 2]];
```

into this:

```
y = [['x', 1], ['z', 4]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to _group_ them _by_ the first element of the array. Search for _"group array of objects"_ and adjust the criteria from using a property of an object to use the first element of an array.

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce with an accumulated object that store sum of key, then use `Object.entries()` to transform it back to an array of array

```js
const y = [
  ["x", 0.5],
  ["x", 0.5],
  ["z", 2],
  ["z", 2],
]

const res = Object.entries(
  y.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + value
    return acc
  }, {})
)

console.log(res)
```